# org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD '

Tags: java, android, gradle

I was modifying and adding some dependencies in my project and then i got this error:

Metadata of https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom   90ms

and some more errors similar to this one
And for the Event Log:

org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'.

My gradle file:

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And Module Dependencies:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hasee.seetravel"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
//            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/res/layout/home',
                    'src/main/res/layout/explore',
                    'src/main/res/layout/camera',
                    'src/main/res/layout/schedule',
                    'src/main/res/layout/me',
                    'src/main/res/layout/video',
                    'src/main/res/layout/drop_menu',
                    'src/main/res/layout',
                    'src/main/res'
            ]
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jcodecraeer:xrecyclerview:1.5.9'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.shuyu:GSYVideoPlayer:4.0.0-beat1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.7'
    implementation 'com.white.countdownbutton:countdownbtn:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.dongjunkun:DropDownMenu:1.0.4'
    implementation 'cn.yipianfengye.android:ad-library:1.0' 
    implementation 'cn.yc:YCDialogLib:3.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0' 
    implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0'  
    implementation 'me.shaohui:bottomdialog:1.1.9' 
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' 
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0' 
    implementation files('libs/Android_Map3D_SDK_V6.0.0_20180211.jar')
}
```

Besides I am a Chinese user but failures also occurred when i turned on my VPN.
Other Settings:
HTTP Proxy:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlH6A.png)

Installed SDK Platform: Android API 28 & Android 8.1(Oreo)

Gradle Settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVNtm.png)

Please Help

Comment: i am getting the same damn error , i have reinstalled the SDK and android studio still not fixing the issue

Comment: Actually I've fixed it today by restoring the build.gradle files days ago(I had backup) . Later on I consulted network services and found it was due to wrong DNS configuration.......So maybe you could first check whether u can access jcenter (make sure ur Internet setting is right.)